# Lower and Upper Riemann Integral

Tags: integration, analysis, riemann-integration

Suppose $f:[0, 1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is given by

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} x  &\text{if}\; x \in \mathbb{Q} \\  0  &\text{if}\; x \notin \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$

Find lower and upper Riemann integral on $[0, 1]$ interval for this function.

I know, looks like easy question. But I'm not sure for upper Riemann integral. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Here's a hint. The rationals are dense in the real numbers so the upper integral will just be the integral of $x$ from 0 to 1.

Comment: Pick an interval, however small. Can you find a rational inside it?

Comment: Yes,  I can. But how can I explain mathematical that? @jlammy

Comment: Thank you @DanielApsley. I'dont search integral. I search lower and upper Riemann integral.

Comment: @DanielApsley I'm so sorry. I dont't read completly your text. I confused. I understand. Thank you and I'm sorry.

Comment: No no. I understand answers. Thank you @hamam_Abdallah